# spring-boot read config files redundantly

Tags: spring-boot

I designed my config files like this:

```
application.yaml
application-a.yaml
application-b.yaml
```

and use `spring.profiles.include` to load config files recursively.

in `application.yaml`, it is

```
spring.profiles.include: a
```

in `application-a.yaml`, it is

```
spring.profiles.include: b
```

Then I run with `--debug` flag and the log output like this

```
Application:597 --- The following profiles are active: a,b # that's right  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Loaded config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Skipped (empty) config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Loaded config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Skipped (empty) config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Skipped (empty) config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Loaded config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Skipped (empty) config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Skipped (empty) config file  
o.s.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener:172 --- Skipped (empty) config file
```

it seems that `ConfigFileApplicationListener` received redundant event from Spring `ApplicationContext`.

Maybe it can be improved, through it affects very slightly.

If you're the developer of Spring Boot Project, thank you for reading this. Does it worth to fix?

Comment: What do you think could be improved? You have three config files and the log output is showing that three have been loaded. Where’s the redundancy?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I think Spring is unnecessary to check-and-load config files more than once, for example, it shouldnot send skipped-event for same file.

Comment: Why do you think it’s the same file? There’s nothing in the log message that says that it is